# How to reset staged and unstaged changes with nodegit

Tags: javascript, git, nodegit

I'm trying to execute `git reset --hard` via nodegit after setting the HEAD to a detached state by doing the following:

```
var oid = 'commit sha';
repo.setHeadDetached(oid);
Reset.reset(repo, oid, Reset.TYPE.HARD);
```

but without any success.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/44779afd0d460011e13a5cba9a47a48119aa472e/vendor/libgit2/include/git2/reset.h):

- http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#setHeadDetached

Look here (searched the project for such a method):
https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=detach

- https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/701
  This ticket is for: **Repository.setHeadDetached fails with an internal assertion**

Another related issue:
https://gitter.im/nodegit/nodegit/archives/2015/04/13